# ¿Cómo cambio el formato de una fecha? R studio

Tags: r, date, rstudio

Esta es la fecha que tengo
[image: fecha excel]

Y esta es la fecha que me importa r studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si la primera imagen es excel, recuerda que una columna de un xls con una fecha, al quitarle el formato, es un número como el que ves en la segunda imagen. PD. Procura no compartir imágenes si puedes compartir texto. Yo lo transformaría en CSV para no lidiar con problemas de formato en las columnas

Comment: Bienvenido Karen Giraldo a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Tu problema no es de formato, es que no se están leyendo correctamente las fechas desde lo que parecería ser un excel. Por favor agrega el código que estás usando para importar el archivo. Saludos.

Comment: @Alfabravo si entiendo que esa sea la forma más fácil, pero quisiera resolver el problema desde R, para no tener que hacer un trabajo manual.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho                                                                                                                   
parser <- ArgumentParser()
parser$add_argument("--input",
                    default = ("datos.parquet"))


args <- parser$parse_args()

base <- read_parquet(args$input) %>%
  glimpse()

Comment: Revisa los enlaces que Patricio te sugirió para que puedas crear y editar tus preguntas fácilmente. El código en el comentario se pierde. Recuerda que puedes usar el enlace [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/391327/edit) que está justo debajo de tu pregunta y de las etiquetas

Comment: Karen, por lo que veo, estás usando `arrow`, no lo conozco, pero lo que si puedo decirte es que la columna Fecha, es simplemente un character que parece tener distintos formatos. Revisa de dónde viene la información original, puede que tengas realmente heterogeneidad en este dato, deberías entonce compartir una muestra de los posibles formato como texto, como para poder analizarlo y darte una respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Una idea simple sería cambiar "-" por "/", aunque también se podría hacer al revés. Quedaría el siguiente código:

```
fecha = gsub("-","/", fecha)
fecha = as.Date(fecha, "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes poner esta formula en ves de base pones el nombre de tu base de datos y en lugar de fecha el nombre de la columna que contiene esa fecha

```
base$Fecha<-as.Date(base$Fecha, origin="1900-01-01")
```